# i get an error decoding a p7m file with openssl

Tags: openssl

on mac os x, trying to decode a p7m xml file with:

`openssl smime -decrypt -in "file.xml.p7m" -inform DER -verify -noverify -out "file.xml"`

return this error:

`Error reading S/MIME message C09D9E0C01000000:error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1188: C09D9E0C01000000:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:349:Type=PKCS7_ISSUER_AND_SERIAL C09D9E0C01000000:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:685:Field=issuer_and_serial, Type=PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO C09D9E0C01000000:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:654:Field=signer_info, Type=PKCS7_SIGNED C09D9E0C01000000:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:685: C09D9E0C01000000:error:0688010A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_ex_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:537:Field=d.sign, Type=PKCS7`

parsing work seamless

`openssl asn1parse -inform der -in "file.xml.p7m"`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

solved, i need to decrypt using cms (Cryptographic Message Syntax), my file probably use newer versions of S/MIME.

install openssl v3xx

`brew install openssl`

`/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin/openssl version`

> OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022)

`/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin/openssl cms -decrypt -in "file.xml.p7m" -inform DER -verify -noverify -out "file.xml"`